# Rewrite Url Zend

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, routes

My site is on Zendframework made. I need a little help with rewrite the url. I have for example this url `http://www.familymoments.de/category/Weihnachtskarten` and now I what to rewrite it without "category", to this url `http://www.familymoments.de/Weihnachtskarten`. how can I do this one? Thx

Comment: give us more information - what you have tried so far!

Comment: I am new to zend framework and I did not so match. I am searching and reading divers articles. All What I understood till now that I need something to change hire:resources.router.routes.category.route = /category/:categ/:page
resources.router.routes.category.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.category.defaults.controller = category
resources.router.routes.category.defaults.action = index
resources.router.routes.category.defaults.categ = n
resources.router.routes.category.defaults.page = 1

Comment: you are reference in your question to ``zend-framework 2`` - your code is ``zend-framework 1```what framework do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom routes. Add this to bootstrap:

```
  //create new route
  $routes['Weihnachtskarten'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
          '/Weihnachtskarten',
          array(
              'module'=>'default',
              'controller'=>'category',
              'action'=>'weihnachtskarten',
          ));

  //add it to router
  $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
  $router->addRoutes($routes);
```